# VideoPlayer - Play video from Android StreamingAssets folder

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play a video file from the streaming assets folder. Works fine on PC but just doesn't load on Android.

```
if (!fileName.EndsWith(".mp4")) fileName = fileName + ".mp4";

var url = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName;

if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_ANDROID
    url = "jar:" + url;
#endif

videoPlayer.url = url;
videoPlayer.Prepare();
```

I was wondering if I was missing a trick on getting the video URL and making it play?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Application.streamingAssetsPath` directly without any prefix?

Comment: `var url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName;` and then change `url = "jar:" + url;` to `url = "jar:file://" + url;` ?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact it won't play on Android, however.

Comment: For the Android replace `url = "jar:" + url;` with `url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName;`

Comment: @Programmer you beautiful person you.